# Creating a file from array in symfony2

Tags: file, symfony, csv

I have to create an array using a symfony2 controller and return the array as a csv file in response so that the user can download it..Wat is the best possible way to do this?  I do not want to store this file in server..

Answer (score 0):

It's not really Symfony related, but you can do this quite easily in PHP:

```
<?php
$lines = array(
    array('foo', 'bar', 'baz'),
    array('lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor'),
);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($line); $i++) {
        echo $line[$i];

        if ($i < count($line) - 1) {
            echo ",";
        } else {
            echo "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a string of your data and then returning it as a Response object.

Your data, for example...

```
$lines = array(
    array('some', 'random', 'stuff'),
    array('in', 'an', 'array'),
);
```

Set your variables

```
$delimeter = ','; // Set the delimeter
$enclosure = '"'; // Set the enclosure
$filename = uniqid(); // Set the filename, for this a unique id
```

Cycle through the lines and fields then combine them into a string (also double up enclosures used if used in the field)

```
$content = '';

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $fields = array();
    foreach ($line as $field)
    {
        $fields[] = $enclosure . str_replace($enclosure,
                        $enclosure . $enclosure, $field) . $enclosure;
    }
    $content .= implode($delimeter, $fields) . "\n";
}
```

Create and return your response object set as a downloadable file

```
$response = new Response($content);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/csv');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 
                            sprintf('attachment; filename="%s.csv"', $filename));

return $response;
```